# How does .net internally call wsdl webservice method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I'd like to understand the fundamental mechanism : as far as I know .net parse the wsdl (using ServiceDescription class) and generate proxy classes that will make the call.

But how are these proxy classes generated ? Through CodeDom or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decompiled wsdl.exe with dotPeek and as far as I understand it uses CodeDomProvider for code generation. This is how `GenerateCode` method's signature looks like.

```
  private void GenerateCode(DiscoveryClientDocumentCollection[] documents, 
     CodeDomProvider codeProvider, WsdlParameters parameters, string outputFileName)
  {
   ...    
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, will also look at dotPeek.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy classes are generated from the metadata. Usually a service would expose it's public contract *and* a metadata contract.

In a WCF service the metadata would be exposed with something like

```
<endpoint address="mex" 
    binding="mexHttpBinding" 
    contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

You can read more about metadata standard [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-metadata/), and WCF [import-export metadata docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731768.aspx).

If no metadata contract is exposed, you cannot generate proxies.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WCF yet more with asmx and wsdl but thanks I guess I need that info also.